# UIKit Dynamics on a UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit-dynamics

Can you add the springy cells effect when scrolling (like in the Messages app on iOS7) to an `UITableView`? I've seen examples of it working on an `UICollectionView`, but absolutely nothing for table views.

Is it just not possible and I should change every table view to a collection view and redo all the cells?

Comment: BTW the **short answer is No**.  UIKit Dynamics is only for UICollectionView, and (2014) explicitly is strictly unavailable for table views.  (Sucks, eh?! :) )

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Every `UICollectionView` has a layout object (a `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass) that describes where each cell should go in the collection view's scroll view and which cells are visible in a given CGRect. `UITableView` doesn't have this, so it would be much harder to do anything that manipulates the position of its cells.

In addition to animating `UIView` objects, UIKit Dynamics can be used to animate `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` directly, which is necessary for a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` style class that has reusable cells that may not all be on screen, but which would still be part of the `UIDynamicAnimator`'s "physics". `UIDynamicAnimator` methods such as `layoutAttributesForCellAtIndexPath:` can then be used to populate your layout object.

There being no equivalent layout object for a `UITableView`, and no equivalent `UIDynamicAnimator` code to operate on off-screen `UITableView` cells, it's likely to be much easier for you to switch to a `UICollectionView` if you want this behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

In the WWDC 2013 session [Exploring Scroll Views in iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#217-video) they talk about doing this effect with a collection view and UIKit Dynamics. I'd imagine that it's much easier to do it with a collection view than a table view since it's easier to position the cells. There may be sample code to go along with the session.